# tomcat closed when i open visualvm_profiler

Tags: java, profiling, tomcat6, visualvm

i run tomcat6 by doubleclick on startup.bat on win2003 . then i open up visualvm1.31. I went to the profiler tab, and press memory, then i can statement on tomcat log, "...cache" then suddenly tomcat shutdown itself, there is no error message.  anyone experience this?

visualvm application status: terminated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a jvm with version at leat 1.6.07. jdk 1.6.06 has a bug which terminates your tomcat if you want to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like it could be a memory issue.  how much ram does your machine have available?

without any other information, i don't think we can help you.  no thread dump, no tomcat log, nothing?

Comment: 32bit window2003, 18gb, do you mean jvm do not have enough memory to create profiler runtime?

Comment: how can you address more than 4gb with only 32 bits?

Comment: i know max address is 4gb. but that is not related to my question.  my tomcat run at -xms/xmx=1gb. visualvm can monitor the memory only the "profiler" tab, when i press "memory", tomcat suddenly shutdown,without any error message